# ROM - COMBINATIONAL MEMORY?

Tags: digital-logic, memory, logic-gates

A combinational circuit only depends on present input values.
Why ROM is considered as combinational memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot change the contents of a true ROM, it should be clear that the output depends only on the inputs, ie, which memory cell is selected by the address inputs, if the output is enabled, etc.

This would not, however be true for a *synchronous* ROM with registered inputs or pipelining.

And it is not true for any sort of RAM, PROM with still alterable state, EPROM, EEPROM, etc as in those cases inputs can establish state which will affect the future relationship between inputs and outputs.  However it may be true if certain inputs (write enable, erase enable, or a voltage needed for that) are prohibited.

Comment: Entered inputs are past values

Comment: No, *present* entered inputs are *present* values, just like with an AND gate.  The point is that because you can't write to a (true) ROM, its asynchronous version has no "memory" of *alterable* state, so the output is only a function of the unalterable state (which is theoretically in the same category as the wiring) and the present inputs.

Comment: So can we destroy data on ROM, like by strong magnetic fields?, and i recently updated my laptop bios version, bios is supposed to be in ROM, how was i able to update that?

Comment: BIOS is generally held in EEPROM, or Flash ROM, not traditional ROM.

Comment: Can you explain the sequence of actions when a pc starts up, especially in regard to ROM and RAM?

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with the question asked here, and would probably be closed as off topic if asked in a distinct question.